# adding column with per-row computed time difference from group start?

Tags: python, pandas

(newbie to python and pandas)

I have a data set of 15 to 20 million rows, each row is a time-indexed observation of a time a 'user' was seen, and I need to analyze the visit-per-day patterns of each user, normalized to their first visit. So, I'm hoping to plot with an X axis of "days after first visit" and a Y axis of "visits by this user on this day", i.e., I need to get a series indexed by a timedelta and with values of visits in the period ending with that delta [0:1, 3:5, 4:2, 6:8,] But I'm stuck very early ...

I start with something like this:

```
rng = pd.to_datetime(['2000-01-01 08:00', '2000-01-02 08:00',
                  '2000-01-01 08:15', '2000-01-02 18:00',
                  '2000-01-02 17:00', '2000-03-01 08:00',
                  '2000-03-01 08:20','2000-01-02 18:00'])
uid=Series(['u1','u2','u1','u2','u1','u2','u2','u3'])
misc=Series(['','x1','A123','1.23','','','','u3'])
df = DataFrame({'uid':uid,'misc':misc,'ts':rng})
df=df.set_index(df.ts)

grouped = df.groupby('uid')
firstseen = grouped.first()
```

The `ts` values are unique to each `uid`, but can be duplicated (two `uid` can be seen at the same time, but any one `uid` is seen only once at any one timestamp)

The first step is (I think) to add a new column to the DataFrame, showing for each observation what the timedelta is back to the first observation for that user. But, I'm stuck getting that column in the DataFrame. The simplest thing I tried gives me an obscure-to-newbie error message:

```
df['sinceseen'] = df.ts - firstseen.ts[df.uid]
...
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

So I tried a brute-force method:

```
def f(row):
    return row.ts - firstseen.ts[row.uid]
df['sinceseen'] = Series([{idx:f(row)} for idx, row in df.iterrows()], dtype=timedelta)
```

In this attempt, `df` gets a `sinceseen` but it's all `NaN` and shows a type of `float` for `type(df.sinceseen[0])` - though, if I just print the Series (in iPython) it generates a nice list of `timedeltas`.

I'm working back and forth through "Python for Data Analysis" and it seems like `apply()` should work, but

```
def fg(ugroup):
    ugroup['sinceseen'] = ugroup.index - ugroup.index.min()
    return ugroup

df = df.groupby('uid').apply(fg)
```

gives me a `TypeError` on the "`ugroup.index - ugroup.index.min(`" even though each of the two operands is a `Timestamp`.

So, I'm flailing - can someone point me at the "pandas" way to get to the data structure Ineed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help you get started?

```
>>> df = DataFrame({'uid':uid,'misc':misc,'ts':rng})
>>> df = df.sort(["uid", "ts"])
>>> df["since_seen"] = df.groupby("uid")["ts"].apply(lambda x: x - x.iloc[0])
>>> df
   misc                  ts uid        since_seen
0       2000-01-01 08:00:00  u1  0 days, 00:00:00
2  A123 2000-01-01 08:15:00  u1  0 days, 00:15:00
4       2000-01-02 17:00:00  u1  1 days, 09:00:00
1    x1 2000-01-02 08:00:00  u2  0 days, 00:00:00
3  1.23 2000-01-02 18:00:00  u2  0 days, 10:00:00
5       2000-03-01 08:00:00  u2 59 days, 00:00:00
6       2000-03-01 08:20:00  u2 59 days, 00:20:00
7    u3 2000-01-02 18:00:00  u3  0 days, 00:00:00

[8 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: So, the key insight I'm taking here is using iloc to get the time from the first row of the group, and ensuring that's the lowest time by sorting on time before taking the group. Right? Solved my problem, thanks!

Comment: @Wayne: you could use `x - x.min()` instead, if that seems more natural to you.  But I like to keep times sorted, and `.iloc[0]` is the usual way to refer to the first in a group, so that was how I first thought of it.